# showing date in cosmos DB

Tags: c#, json, datetime, azure-cosmosdb, azure-iot-hub

I have a cosmos DB on Azure, that saves data from my IoT device. I want to add date to the json object that contains data in cosmos DB.

I have defined a class in the IoTHubTrigger function that holds the data:

```
public class SensorItem{
  [JsonProperty("id")]
  public string Id {get; set;}
  public double OxygenLevels {get; set;}
  public double SleepHours {get; set;}
  public string InhalerStatuses {get;set;}
  public string Date {get;set;} }
```

I also defined a function that the output parameter is set to be a new SensorItem using the values from the simulated device app. This will create a document and insert it into the Cosmos database collection. A new item is inserted everytime the simulated device app sends data. The IotHubTriggerFunction is defined as below:

```
public static class IotHubTriggerFunction
{
    private static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    [FunctionName("IotHubTriggerFunction")]
    public static void Run([IoTHubTrigger("messages/events", Connection = "AzureEventHubConnectionString")] EventData message,
    [CosmosDB(databaseName: "IoTData",
                             collectionName: "simdata",
                             ConnectionStringSetting = "cosmosDBConnectionString")] out SensorItem output,
                   ILogger log)
    {
    log.LogInformation($"C# IoT Hub trigger function processed a message: {Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message.Body.Array)}");
    var jsonBody = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message.Body);
    dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonBody);
    double OxygenLevel = data.OxygenLevel;
    double SleepHour = data.SleepHour;
    string InhalerStatus = data.InhalerStatus;


output = new SensorItem
{
    Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
    OxygenLevels = OxygenLevel,
    SleepHours = SleepHour,
    InhalerStatuses = InhalerStatus,
    Date = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("u",DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);
 };}
[FunctionName("GetData")]
  public static IActionResult GetData(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = "sensordata")] HttpRequest req,
    [CosmosDB(databaseName: "IoTData",
              collectionName: "simdata",
              ConnectionStringSetting = "cosmosDBConnectionString",
                  SqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM c")] IEnumerable<SensorItem> sensorItem,
              ILogger log)
  {
    return new OkObjectResult(sensorItem);
  }
}}
```

However when I run it, I cannot see the Date in my cosmos DB.

Furthermore, I defined a http trigger function and bind it to the cosmos DB, but when I run it and copy the URL in my browser, I get 0001-01-01T00:00:00 as the date, not the current date.

Does anybody know how to solve the issue?

Comment: You need to use 8601 with Cosmos and store as a string, details here, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/working-with-dates

Comment: Thank you for your response. I editted my code (above) according the link you've shared. However, I still can't see the dates when I press "execute query" in cosmos DB.  Can you help me to solve the problem?

Comment: What query? This looks like an http trigger that inserts data into Cosmos. Binding how? Does this work if you don't have Date in here? Need more detail to help.

Comment: Does the below answer help?

Answer (score 0):

Convert below line:

```
  public string Date {get;set;}
```

To:

```
  public DateTime Date {get;set;}
```

And assign value like this:

```
output = new SensorItem
{
    OxygenLevels = OxygenLevel,
    SleepHours = SleepHour,
    InhalerStatuses = InhalerStatus,
    Date = DateTime.UtcNow
 };
```

When you save `output` in CosmosDb directly, it will automatically convert itself to **ISO 8601 UTC standard**.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to re-produce the issue using your same code but I am able to see the proper date in Cosmos Database.

[image: cosmosDb records www.compilemode.com]

As per your explanation, I understood that you have following data flow.

**Simulated IoT Devices **----- I**oT Hub** ---- **IoT Hub Trigger Azure Function** --- **CosmosDB**

Once data comes to the IoT Hub trigger, you are assigning to your defined output class and preparing the payload for CosmosDB and inserting the item. I hope my understanding is correct.
Based on your explanation, the following are my observations.

- Ensure the date value is coming properly from the IoT hub device payload.
- You have defined the id parameter but not assigned any value in the
  Out parameter payload preparation.
- Instead of defining a separate variable for local date, assign value directly to the Out parameter binding of SensorItem class.
- Create a separate method (out of the function binding method) for Processing IoT Hub trigger data which is coming to the function binding method.

I am putting my observation and re-produced steps together which you can try.

Your **SensorItem.cs** Class

```
 public class SensorItem
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public double OxygenLevels { get; set; }
    public double SleepHours { get; set; }
    public string InhalerStatuses { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public string AnotherDate { get; set; }
}
```

Then creates a separate method inside the your IoT Hub trigger function which will take the IoT Hub trigger payload as a parameter and process it to the Cosmos DB.

```
 public async Task AddTelemertyToCosmosDB(SensorItem item)
    {
        CosmosClient cosmosClient = new CosmosClient(EndpointUrl, AuthorizationKey);
        Container container = cosmosClient.GetContainer(YourDatabaseId, YourContainerId);
       

        //Preparing payload from IoT hub trigger data
        var  output = new SensorItem
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
            OxygenLevels = item.OxygenLevels,
            SleepHours = item.SleepHours,
            InhalerStatuses = item.InhalerStatuses,
           //Changed code to assign local date
            Date = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("u", DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo)
        };
        //Inserting data to the Cosmos Database
        await container.CreateItemAsync(output);
    
    }
```

In the preceding code we changed the logic to assign the local date and we also assigned value to the id parameter and some code changes (don't know your Cosmos DataBase client code logic).

Here is inserted a record into the azure cosmos database with the proper date.

[image: inserting data into the azure cosmos database]

I hope it gives you the hint. Let me know if required any input.

Comment: Many thanks for your explanation. I changed the Date as you told so, but still can't see the Date in cosmos DB. I uploaded the rest of my code. could you please take a look and let me know what's the problem? is it possible that my cosmos DB has a problem?

Comment: Can You send the your IoT Hub trigger Azure function code and sample payload which you are getting from IoT Hub (from simulated device)

Comment: Don't know what violets the stack overflow policy if I asked you to share outside because here there is no option. Can you do one thing update your question with same details just make sure you not included any sensitive details such as connectionString etc.

Comment: I couldn't post my code here. It gave me an error that most of your post is code. I also tried to copy it in the text format but it gave an error again to post it in the code format

Comment: Go to my profile and connect me on my social media account